# How to print the hexadecimal values of a given dmp file content

Tags: java, regex, hex

I have some memory dumps (.DMP and .raw windows memory files). I want to print the hexadecimal values of the memory dump's content by reading the memory dump. Because i want to search through a particular hexadecimal header and footer and grab the content. I am suppose to grab the content with using regular expressions and i have no idea about how to get the hexadecimal value by reading the memory dump. I am doing some experiment in file carving. SO please give you creative ideas and codes that i can use to implement this task.

Comment: The regex is the easy part, just use `\xhh` notation. The hard part is to get the content into a string so that no byte is lost and each byte is mapped directly to the Unicode code point of the same value.

Comment: What is the expected behavior for the regex you are looking for to achieve? Will you happen to have test cases? What are the specifications? Please take a [tour] to learn the standards of our questions here. Welcome to [so]!